# How to call a sub-object property in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

Let's say that I have two classes, "Product" and "Brand".

A **Product** has the following properties:
-ProductID
-ProductName
-ProductBrandID
-ProductCost

And a **Brand**:
-BrandID
-BrandName
-BrandLogo

Let's say that in the Product class, i've:

GetID() returning an Integer
GetName() returning a String
GetBrand() returning a **Brand object**

I already made GetBrand() to successfully return the entire Brand object, but how can I refer to a property of this Brand object?

***In another words:***

How can I get the BrandName property from a **Brand** object returned from a **Product** object?

```
$Product = new Product(10); //"Create" a Product object and load the Product #10 from DB;  
$BrandName = $Product->GetBrand()->getName(); //How to do this?
```

PS: I want to avoid a subclass, since I will need to call the Brand class in another context, without refering to a Product first.

PS²: How this "method" is called?

Comment: Does Brand has getName() method? Have you tried $product->GetBrand()->BandName?

Comment: @JuniorZancan Check my answer and if you have any doubt let me know...

Comment: @YashParekh Turns out I was doing the right way, but because of an error in the DB query, the class was being called with a 0 id and returning null... Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have two way entity association mappings on both the `id` fields :-

```
$productOdj = new Product(10);  
$Brand = $productOdj->getBrand();
$brandObj = new Brand($Brand->getId());
```

Hope it works for you.
Happy Coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can create method callBrand inside Product class and get the brand name

```
function callBrand()
 {
   $Brand= new Brand();
   $BrandName = $Brand->BrandName();
   echo $BrandName;
 }
```